# Running NodeJS project in Visual Studio Code with yarn

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I have a NodeJS project which I can start from command line with `yarn start` command. My `package.json` looks similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "My Name",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn dev",
    "dev": "yarn stop && pm2 start pm2-dev.yaml && webpack-dev-server --progress",
    "prod": "yarn stop && yarn build && pm2 start pm2-prod.yaml",
    "build": "rimraf dist lib && babel src -d lib --ignore test.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress",
    "stop": "rimraf logs/* && pm2 delete all || true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
    "ejs": "2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint": "^3.13.0",
    "pm2": "^2.3.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

I am trying to start this project in debugging mode with Visual Studio Code but with almost no luck. I have defined my launch configuration in VS Code `launch.json` file like this:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "yarn",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "start"
      ],
      "port": 5858,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "timeout": 10000
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem with this configuration is that it usually times-out because `webpack-dev-server` build is longer than 10 seconds. I can increase the `timeout` in my configuration, but I have noticed that VS Code results with a message `Cannot connect to runtime process (timeout after 30000 ms).` eventually, so I assume that this is not a good solution. Also, my breakpoints are ignored with this kind of config which tells me that I am definitely doing something wrong here.

This is the first time I am trying out Visual Studio Code and I usually don't use NodeJS, but I got this project with all these scripts in `package.json` already defined so I'm trying to adopt to it and therefore all the confusion about how to run it properly.

Can Visual Studio Code run a project like this with full debugging functionality at all, and if so, how should I configure my launch script?

Comment: what I usually do for debugging is run the build process manually. then run the vs code debug. never tried to build and debug using vs code at in 1  shot

Answer (score 43):

I ended up having the following configuration in `launch.json`:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch via Yarn",
    "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeArgs": ["start:debug"],
    "port": 5858
}
```

And the following entry in the `scripts` property inside `package.json`:

```
"start:debug": "node --inspect-brk=5858 ./server/index.js",
```

You could include a `timeout` key (which defaults to 10000) and increase its value if have any `prestart:debug` script in your `package.json` which could lead to delay the launch of the actual node app.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't show the terminal output for anywhere to view.

Answer (score 2):

I can't specifically answer the webpack parts of the question.  However, your script above won't work because you haven't enabled debugging.  Exposing debugging allows a debugger to attach to this process, and it also blocks program execution until a debugger attaches.  You'll need to make another script in your package.json that allows for debugging.  Then, you can use your debugging-specific script to debug and your non-debugging script to run normally.  For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn dev",
    "dev": "node entry.js",
    "dev-debug": "node --inspect-brk=5858 entry.js",
```

Then, in your launch.json replace "start" with "dev-debug".  The debugging port is already set to 5858 in both launch.json and package.json, so this should work.  The key is running node with the --inspect-brk command, forcing the execution of the node app to stop until a debugger attaches to it.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044602/9423651) - to get mine working I had to add the following to my package.json (the exec was still required) -

```
"start:debug": "nodemon --inspect-brk=5858 --exec \"babel-node\" src/index.js"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a link to this pervious answer with an [edit]. Otherwise it could happen that the sorting changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information shared in this thread, [What exactly is the 'react-scripts start' command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722133/what-exactly-is-the-react-scripts-start-command), by @johndpope.

Here is the setup I used in vscode's `launch.json` file in `configurations` section for launching a ***react*** process.

```
{
        "name": "Launch: Frontend Server",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js",
        "args": ["start"],
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
}
```

So, response to the original post, you may try to see what is the script used in `rimraf` library.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used the debugged in VS Code however I'm using `nodemon` to debug with Chrome with a `shell` script.

```
bin_dir="$__dirname/../node_modules/.bin"
src_dir="$__dirname/../src"

"$bin_dir/nodemon" --ext js,yaml \
    --watch "$src_dir/package.json" \
    --watch "$src_dir" \
    "$src_dir/index.js" \
    --exec "yarn && babel-node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"
```

Open `chrome://inspect/#devices` and start up your debugger