# What exactly is the 'react-scripts start' command?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

I've been working with a React project using `create-react-app` and I have two options to start the project:

**First way:**

`npm run start` with the definition at the `package.json` like this:

`"start": "react-scripts start",`

**Second way:**

`npm start`

What is the difference between these two commands? And, what is the purpose of the `react-scripts start`?

I tried to find the definition, but I just found a package with this name. I still don't know what is the use of this command?

Comment: "start" is a name of a script, in `npm` you run scripts like this `npm run scriptName`, `npm start` is also a short for `npm run start`

Comment: `react-scripts start` is the proper command to run the React app in dev mode. This command is stored in package.json so you don't have to memorize it and may simply type the usual `npm run start` instead. `npm start` is a shortcut for the latter.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

#### create-react-app and react-scripts

`react-scripts` is a set of scripts from the [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) starter pack. create-react-app helps you kick off projects without configuring, so you do not have to setup your project by yourself.

`react-scripts start` sets up the development environment and starts a server, as well as hot module reloading. You can read [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#whats-included) to see what everything it does for you.

with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) you have following features out of the box.

> - React, JSX, ES6, and Flow syntax support.
> - Language extras beyond ES6 like the object spread operator.
> - Autoprefixed CSS, so you don’t need -webkit- or other prefixes.
> - A fast interactive unit test runner with built-in support for coverage reporting.
> - A live development server that warns about common mistakes.
> - A build script to bundle JS, CSS, and images for production, with hashes and sourcemaps.
> - An offline-first service worker and a web app manifest, meeting all the Progressive Web App criteria.
> - Hassle-free updates for the above tools with a single dependency.

#### npm scripts

[`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) is a shortcut for `npm run start`.

[`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) is used to run scripts that you define in the `scripts` object of your package.json

if there is no `start` key in the scripts object, it will default to `node server.js`

Sometimes you want to do more than the react scripts gives you, in this case you can do `react-scripts eject`. This will transform your project from a "managed" state into a not managed state, where you have full control over dependencies, build scripts and other configurations.

Comment: Do you know how to run it on production?

Comment: to use it in productions you would say `npm run build`. this will create a build folder. this folder you may then serve. e.g. `npm install -g serve`and then `serve -s build` https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

Comment: It seems like `react-scripts` should be included in a project as a `devDependency`, is that right? Or should it be in the normal `dependency` section of `package.json`?

Comment: in my opinion, for client side rendered applications, it does not matter if devDependency or not, because the bundler is what matters here. leveraging devDependencies makes sense in node applications

Answer (score 127):

As Sagiv b.g. pointed out, the `npm start` command is a shortcut for `npm run start`. I just wanted to add **a real-life example** to clarify it a bit more.

The setup below comes from the `create-react-app` github repo. The [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/package.json) defines a bunch of scripts which define the actual flow.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
  "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
  "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
  "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
  "start-js": "react-scripts start"
},
```

For clarity, I added a diagram. 
[image]

The blue boxes are references to scripts, all of which you could executed directly with an `npm run <script-name>` command. But as you can see, actually there are only 2 practical flows:

- `npm run start`
- `npm run build`

The grey boxes are commands which can be executed from the command line.

So, for instance, if you run `npm start` (or `npm run start`) that actually translate to the `npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js` command, which is executed from the commandline.

In my case, I have this special `npm-run-all` command, which is a popular plugin that searches for scripts that start with "build:", and executes all of those. I actually don't have any that match that pattern. But it can also be used to run multiple commands in parallel, which it does here, using the `-p <command1> <command2>` switch. **So, here it executes 2 scripts, i.e. `watch-css` and `start-js`.** (Those last mentioned scripts are watchers which monitor file changes, and will only finish when killed.)

- The `watch-css` makes sure that the `*.scss` files are translated to `*.css`files, and looks for future updates.
- The `start-js` points to the `react-scripts start` which hosts the website in a development mode.

**In conclusion, the `npm start` command is configurable. If you want to know what it does, then you have to check the `package.json` file.** (and you may want to make a little diagram when things get complicated).

Comment: I just tried creating new project via `create-react-app` and I have different `scripts` inside `package.json`. For example `"start": "react-scripts start"`

Comment: @MáraToner it's perfectly possible that the default setup has evolved to something else by now. It's likely to continue evolving in the future. Fortunately, (as mentioned above) the `package.json` is configurable to run any CLI tool or script. So, the essence of this answer should still hold valid.

Comment: Gorgeous diagram.  Is there a tool that can generate that from a package.json file's "scripts" section?  That would be absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 37):

succinctly - it runs this

```
node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start
```

Answer (score 8):

"start" is a name of a script, in npm you run scripts like this `npm run scriptName`, `npm start` [is also a short for](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) `npm run start`

As for "react-scripts" this is a script related specifically to [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/package.json#L14)

Answer (score 3):

**`npm start`** is the short form for **`npm run start`**

You can check about it here **[Difference between npm start and npm run start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358235/difference-between-npm-start-and-npm-run-start)**

**react-scripts start**

react-scripts is a set of scripts to support the creation, development and testing of react applications. It is used by create-react-app.

create-react-app is the officially supported way to create single-page React applications. create react app uses webpack to parse and bundle the application.
webpack parses the application and creates a dependency graph from its entry point specified in the webpack config file. while parsing, webpack uses babel to transpile the application to JavaScript, which has better support across browsers.
Webpack uses the generated dependency graph to create a single JavaScript file consisting of the application source code and modules used by the app, injects the file via script tag into `public/index.html`, and starts a development server on `http://localhost:3000`. Navigating to this URL in the browser will show a live, interactive instance of your application. Any changes saved to the source code will reflect in the running app instance automatically.
You can read more about this topic more on [here](https://github.com/nitishdayal/cra_closer_look#yarn-startnpm-start)

Answer (score 0):

When we use npm start in a project created with create-react-app, it essentially executes react-scripts start under the hood. Both commands are the same and are used to start the development server for React application.