# npm run build freezes - how to debug this?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js app that is working fine when I run it with `npm start` but when I try to build it the process freezes. This is what I see:

```
$ npm run build

> reactsearch@0.1.0 build /home/ppdevts4/public_html/reactsearch
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
```

I can leave it for 2 hours or 2 days and it never changes.
On the server I can see that the CPU peaks at about 30%, RAM at about 10% and Input/Output usage at about 50%. So it does not seem like resources are a problem.

I found a file called error_log in public_html and no new entries have been added to it after I ran `npm run build`.

Any suggests how to debug this please?
I'm new to node.js.

Thanks,
Phil

**Updated ...**

After removing server limits the script now ends with an error. This is what I see in the debug.log in .npm/_logs folder:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/ppdevts4/bin/node', '/home/ppdevts4/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~prebuild: reactsearch@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: reactsearch@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: PATH: /home/ppdevts4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ppdevts4/public_html/reactsearch/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/ppdevts4/.local/bin:/home/ppdevts4/bin
9 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: CWD: /home/ppdevts4/public_html/reactsearch
10 silly lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: reactsearch@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/ppdevts4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ppdevts4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactsearch@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ppdevts4/public_html/reactsearch
16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.25.10.el7.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/home/ppdevts4/bin/node" "/home/ppdevts4/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.9.1
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reactsearch@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reactsearch@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Another post said `npm install react-scripts --save` might fix it but the error log is the same afterwards.

Any suggestions how to fix this error?

**Updated 14 Oct 2019**

I created a t3.s instance on AWS with 8 CPUs and 32GB RAM and it gave a similar error so it does not seem like this is caused by lack of memory.

Here is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/ec2-user/bin/node', '/home/ec2-user/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v12.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~prebuild: reactsearch@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: reactsearch@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: PATH: /home/ec2-user/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ec2-user/public_html/reactsearch/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
9 verbose lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: CWD: /home/ec2-user/public_html/reactsearch
10 silly lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle reactsearch@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: reactsearch@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid reactsearch@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/ec2-user/public_html/reactsearch
16 verbose Linux 4.14.146-93.123.amzn1.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/home/ec2-user/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.9.1
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error reactsearch@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the reactsearch@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: The command that seems to be running is "react-scripts build", so I'd look into that. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722133/what-exactly-is-the-react-scripts-start-command).

Comment: Please check the title of the command prompt/terminal. If it says anything but the command being executed, hit ctrl + c only once and see if the execution proceeds further...

Comment: AdityaParab - the title of the putty window shows the name of the current directory. It does not change when I run any command or press Ctrl-C once, it only changes when I change directory.

Comment: It looks like the server may have been limiting the number of processes that could be run for the account. I removed all limits and the script now completes but the build folder only contains a few template files. I'll add info to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue after running `apt-get upgrade`. I restarted the console and everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that can cause this.

In my `index.ejs` file I accidentally wrote a comment like this:

```
<! this is a badly formatted html comment>
```

i.e. without the double dashes.

`npm run build` let me get away with that, but `npm run build-prod` just hung.

Took a while to figure that out.