# Creating an optimized build freezes and never completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am trying to build my react app. But when I run "npm run build", The terminal freezes on "Creating and optimized production build..." and never finish.
This is my JSON file. I tried on 16 GB ram also.

I have deleted package lock file and also rebuild the dependencies. But it remains same.
There is no specific solution anywhere, if anyone has solution please let me know.

```
{
  "name": "demoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.33",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-react-pdf": "^4.12.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-material": "^4.43.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2021.3.1109",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.0",
    "dom-to-pdf": "^0.2.2",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
    "pdf-viewer-reactjs": "^2.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.10.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-loader": "^2.4.7",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.21",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.0.18",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341077/npm-run-build-freezes-how-to-debug-this

Comment: Thanks but this question does not have specific answer. If you know how to solve this please let me know.. Thanks

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Comment: Yes I tried by building react-scripts again but same issue.

Comment: Can you try inside another terminal like `Git bash`?

Comment: And update your node.js to a newer version

Comment: tried this one also but same

Comment: Have you tried building it on a different computer? .. Just in case.

Comment: yes i tried on two systems

Comment: Is it on Windows? Do you have latest Node.js (v16+) and npm?

Comment: I have faced this freezing behavior twice; both were caused by a missing dependency. It's just weird that no errors get raised when this happen.

Answer (score 8):

Check to see if you have a local server running in another terminal (eg. localhost:3000 ).

If you do, end that server instance by terminating the batch job (with Ctrl+C) and try running `npm run build` again.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue. Check your `package.json` for react-scripts, if the version is <5.0.0 upgrade it to at least `"react-scripts": "5.0.0"`.

Do a `yarn install` or `npm install` again, then `yarn build` or `npm run build` as the case may be.

Let me know if this works for you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If the process is stuck, it could be due to a lack in computing resources.

I would recommend investigating the currently running processes.

Try running `sudo htop` on a different terminal window and then run `sudo npm run build`.

You might find another process is taking too much memory, causing the build process to hang.

You may need to kill or restart such processes to complete the build.
It would be a good idea to check why those processes take so much memory, but that's besides the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue. I searched for many solutions and finally discovered that it was due to the insufficient memory on my server. **The server got stuck while packaging because of the low memory. Please check if your server's memory usage is normal.** If you're facing a similar problem, I recommend stopping other services first and then proceeding with the packaging